# HeidiSQL: count all students in different courses

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the amount of students from each course, but the amount JOINs required stumbles me a bit.

Tables: `student`, `group` and `course`

`students quantity` was taken from the `group` table

```
SELECT id, SUM(`students quantity`) AS students_all FROM course
JOIN student ON student.group = course.id
JOIN group ON group.`students quantity`=student.id
GROUP BY student.course
ORDER BY `students_all` DESC
```

What confuses me is this part: **I know, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what exactly**

```
SUM(`students quantity`) AS students_all FROM course
JOIN student ON student.group = course.id
JOIN group ON group.`students quantity`=student.id
```

The result I have is the **single** `course.id` displayed and `students_all` having all the students overall, instead of the all students from specific course.

### What I need to recieve from the query

`course.id`: 1 2 3 4

`students_all`: 7 7 6 7

### What I get

`course.id`: 1

`students_all`: 27

---

Since I have Russian inteface, I'll post samples this way, to avoid confusion

[Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEMqq.png)

[Student (excluding all the irrelevant data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fwbE.png)

As for the **course** table: the only relevant column there is *ID* which range is 1-4

Comment: What is the table group for? Can you provide sample data for your 3 tables?

Comment: @P.Salmon

the group table is there to differ the students studying different languages:

1st course: 1 group for english, 1 for french, 1 for german
2nd course: 1 for english... well, you know the rest

Comment: @P.Salmon added the samples in OP, you might want to check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very late reply of mine, but I solved it myself. No need to answer!